# Traveling International - Are the airports (airliners) communicating with the medical offices?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19

My mother in law came to visit us back in December of 2019.  She has a valid green card but got stuck here due to Covid 19.  Now she is ready to fly back to Iraq.  In order to fly she will be taking Turkish Airlines (operated by JetBlue Airways) to fly from DTW (Detroit, MI) to Boston.  Then from Boston to Turkey.  Then from Turkey to Iraq.

The travel agent is stating that we need a Covid 19 PCR Test two days PRIOR to flying out.  Her ticket is for the 28th of August, which means she needs this test on the 26th of August with the results.  Each place I call state that they either do not do this test or refer me to another lab / office.

I finally found one place that may do the test however they stated that it could take 36 to 48 hours to get a result and even it might take longer.  The risk is high as she is supposed to fly out on the 28th of August.  Im curious why the airliners impose these restrictions yet the medical folks cannot adhere to these restrictions?  Am I doing something wrong or am I not understanding what the rules / regulations required to fly internationally are right now?

Comment: Often it's the destination's government who imposes these requirements and whether the place of departure has the capability to do that is not really a concern to the destination's public health consideration (unless it is scientifically/technically impossible, which isn't the case here, the US simply has too little capacity compared to people that need test).

Comment: Is the final destination in the Kurdistan Region? I can only find requirements of PCR test for that region so far.

Comment: She would fly to Erbil, Iraq eventually.

Comment: @zhantongz - I  read this `Travelers arriving at Erbil International Airport or at land border crossings should possess a negative COVID-19 test result that is less than 48 hours old.  Travelers without a COVID-19 result will be tested at their cost.  Arriving travelers must sign a pledge to quarantine for 48 hours at their destination until they receive results.  Persons with positive results will be transferred to COVID-19 clinics. ` from this site: https://iq.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information/

Comment: @zhantongz - I don't know if that means she doesnt really need this test or not ?  As one of the sentences says "Travelers without a covid-19 result will be tested at their cost."

Comment: @JonH it is what it seems. The negative part is that she will have to self-quarantine for two days when arriving at home, and that she will have to pay whatever the official price is (although I am willing to bet that it will be cheaper than in the USA).

Comment: @SJuan76 - I dont think she minds the self quarantine as she doesn't go out a lot anyhow.  I just don't know if this website reflects the correct information.  I'm scared to book an 1100 flight only to find out I needed the test...and the testing centers are not prepared for this...

Comment: @SJuan76 - I found some more supporting information.  From the erbil international airport website found here: https://erbilairport.com/INFO06/F_INFO06_01_02.aspx?articleId=468 specifically it says "...those without, will be required to undertake a PCR test, at their own cost, at the airport. All arriving passengers will be required to sign a pledge form committing to 14 days self-isolation following their arrival in the Kurdistan region of Iraq.
Official delegations, business people and tourists on short stay trips are not required to self-isolate if their PCR test is negative."

Comment: I would take it as them saying they need a test result from no more than two days prior to her flying out.  So ask the medical office when she should take the test so as to get a result 48 hours or less before she flies out.  (Give them the date and time range you need the result and see if they can help you based on that.)

Comment: Also, I note that you said the _travel agent_ states you need a result from two days prior.  Ask the travel agent her source on that requirement.  Then go to the source (e.g. the airline) and ask for more details.

Answer (score 2):

> Im curious why the airliners impose these restrictions yet the medical folks cannot adhere to these restrictions?

Because they are different entities doing different things for different reasons. First of all, this has nothing with the airliners. The requirements to provide negative test on arrival come from the local governments. These governments are mainly concerned about keeping their own population safe and the economy alive. Travel is a low priority. So the government is saying. "You can enter but you have to prove to us that you are Covid negative. How you do this is your problem and if you don't like it, just stay put where you are".

The idea here is that you get tested BEFORE you hop on a plane, so it should be done in the departure country over which the arrival country has no control of in the first place.  However, the departure country is in the same boat: their priorities are population safety and economy and travel is just not that important. In many countries test resources are precious and limited, and so they are primarily used for people who have a good reason to be tested: people with symptoms, front line workers, essential workers, etc. Again, travel is just "nice to have".

That's actually really bad for the airlines, so some of them are actively trying to help. Lufthansa, for example, has collaborated with testing company to do same day testing right in Frankfurt airport when you arrive.

Comment: Its not nice to have when your home is in that country.  And my point is if these types of requirements are made and travel is allowed they should make sure they can REALLY be made otherwise its a waste of peoples time and money!  On the point of they do not communicate that is THEIR problem not mine.